# Issue with jQuery when trying to get form field value using element's ID

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, django

I am encountering an issue in my JavaScript code where I use jQuery to get the value of a form field by using the element's ID. I use it for my back in my Python Django APP

My code looks like this:

javascript

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#addMore, .addMoreInlineItems').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const className = $(this).data('type');
        const form_idx = $(`#id_${className}s-TOTAL_FORMS`).val();
        ...
    });
    ...
});
```

The idea is that when a button is clicked, I retrieve a 'type' data from this button, and I try to use this value to get the value of a form field by using its ID. For example, if className is 'card_language', then the ID I am looking for is 'id_card_languages-TOTAL_FORMS'.

However, I find that form_idx is undefined, which suggests either the element with the specified ID does not exist in the DOM, or the element exists but has no value.

The aim of this code is that when a button is clicked, it retrieves a 'type' data attribute from this button, then uses this value to obtain a corresponding form field's value by using its ID. For example, if className is 'card_language', then the ID I am looking for is 'id_card_languages-TOTAL_FORMS'.

However, I've noticed that form_idx is undefined, which suggests that either the element with the specified ID does not exist in the DOM, or the element exists but has no value.

The purpose of form_idx in this context is to act as a numbering system to generate unique IDs for each new form line. This system is crucial for my implementation, as it allows me to save each line separately with its unique ID.

Despite my checks that the HTML element with the correct ID exists in the DOM, and the ID matches exactly in the JavaScript code and the HTML, I still cannot retrieve the value of the form field. I also ensured that the script runs after the DOM is fully loaded, but I am still facing the same issue.

As it stands, I am unable to save each line separately due to this issue, which is a crucial requirement for my application.

What could be causing this issue? How can I obtain the value of the element as expected so that I can save each line separately with its unique ID?

Comment: Your code, as *minimally* provided with *extrapolated* html, works fine:  https://jsfiddle.net/  If it's not working for you then it could be that you have the wrong ID or there's something "special" about the result of `.data("type")` - eg if it contains a space, full-stop or # then `$("#id"+classname` won't work.   If you would care to include some HTML, we might be able to find the issue.  See [mcve].

Comment: *I find that form_idx is undefined* then your #addMore button doesn't have a `data-type` attribute.